# Как убрать запрос email в iframe приложении vk?

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте, iframe

Всем привет!
Никак не могу получить одобрение приложения iframe в vk. Модераторы пишут, что "необходимо убрать запрос e-mail в настройках", однако совершенно непонятно, о каких настройках идет речь. Код уже весь перерыли, несколько раз убедились, что строк типа scope=email нигде нету. Не может же email как-то по-другому запрашиваться? Вот, взгляните, пожалуйста на код:

```html
<a href="'.$CONF['url'].'/index.php?vk=true&state='.$_SESSION['state'].'">Войти в приложение</a>

<?
  if(isset($_GET['vk']) && $settings['vkappid']) {
    $reg = new register();
    $reg->db = $db;
    $reg->url = $CONF['url'];
    $reg->username = $_POST['username'];
    $reg->password = $_POST['password'];
    $reg->email = $_POST['email'];
    $reg->captcha = $_POST['captcha'];
    $reg->captcha_on = $settings['captcha'];
    $reg->message_privacy = $settings['mprivacy'];
    $reg->like_notification = $settings['notificationl'];
    $reg->comment_notification = $settings['notificationc'];
    $reg->shared_notification = $settings['notifications'];
    $reg->chat_notification = $settings['notificationd'];
    $reg->friend_notification = $settings['notificationf'];
    $reg->verified = $settings['verified'];
    $reg->email_like = $settings['email_like'];
    $reg->email_comment = $settings['email_comment'];
    $reg->email_new_friend = $settings['email_new_friend'];
    $reg->sound_new_notification = $settings['sound_new_notification'];
    $reg->sound_new_chat = $settings['sound_new_chat'];
    $reg->vkapp = $settings['vkapp'];
    $reg->vkappid = $settings['vkappid'];
    $reg->vkappsecret = $settings['vkappsecret'];
    $reg->vkcode = $_GET['code'];
    $reg->vkstate = $_GET['state'];
    $TMPL['registerMsg'] = $reg->vk();

    header("Location: ".$CONF['url']."/index.php?a=profile&u=".$reg->username);
  }
  
  
  function vk() {
    if($this->vkapp) {
      
      $api_id = *******; // здесь реальный id приложения
      $secret_key = '**************'; // здесь реальный защищенный ключ
  
          $auth_key   = $_SESSION['vk_auth_key'];
          $viewer_id  = $_SESSION['vk_viewer_id'];
          if(md5($api_id."_".$viewer_id."_".$secret_key)!=$auth_key) exit($error_text);
      
      
      // Get user's ID + add 'id' line before his ID
      $generator = $_SESSION['vk_viewer_id'];
      $user->screen_name = 'id'.$generator;
      
      //APIServerPHPClass initialization: get user's first_name &  last_name
      require 'vkapi.class.php';
       
      $VK = new vkapi($api_id, $secret_key);
      $resp = $VK->api('users.get', array('uids'=>$generator));
      
      $polar_first_name = $resp['response'][0]['first_name'];
      $polar_last_name = $resp['response'][0]['last_name'];
      
      
      if($_SESSION['state'] == null || ($_SESSION['state'] != $this->vkstate)) {
        header("Location: ".$this->url);
      }
      
      if(!empty($user->screen_name)) {
        $this->screen_name = $user->screen_name;
        $this->first_name = $polar_first_name;
        $this->last_name = $polar_last_name;
        
        $checkScreenName = $this->verify_if_screenname_exists();
        // If user already exist
        
        if($checkScreenName) {
          // Set sessions and log-in
          $_SESSION['username'] = $checkScreenName['username'];
          $_SESSION['password'] = $checkScreenName['password'];

          // Redirect user
          header("Location: ".$this->url);
        } else {
          $this->username = $this->screen_name;
          $this->password = $this->generatePassword(8);
          $this->query();
          
          $_SESSION['username'] = $this->username;
          $_SESSION['password'] = md5($this->password);
          
          return 1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
?>
```

Вот так выглядит html-код страницы:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.timeago.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/functions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://vkontakte.ru/js/api/xd_connection.js?2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function postOnVkWall() {
    VK.api('wall.post',{message: 'Текст_сообщения', attachments: 'vkapp/index.php?a=welcome'},function(data) { 
      if (data.response) { 
        alert('Запись опубликована на Вашей стене!');
        document.location.reload(); 
      }
      if (data.error) { 
        alert('К сожалению, при публикации произошла ошибка.');
        document.location.reload(); 
      }
    });
  }
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({
    openEffect : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none'
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="height:auto !important; min-height:730px;" id="page">
<div id="loading-bar"><dd></dd><dt></dt></div>
<div class="topbar">
  <div class="header">
    <a href="/vkapp/index.php?a=welcome" rel="loadpage"><div class="menu_btn logo-container"><div class="logo"></div></div></a>
    <div class="search-input"><input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Поиск людей, #хэштегов, !групп" autocomplete="off" value=""></div>
    <a href="/vkapp/index.php?a=welcome" rel="loadpage" title="Присоединиться"><div class="topbar-button">Присоединиться</div></a>
  </div>
  <div class="search-container"></div>
</div>
<div id="content">
  
<div class="row-welcome content-welcome">
  <div class="row-body">
    <div class="welcome-inner">
      <div class="welcome-message">
        <div class="welcome-title">
          Title
        </div>
        <div class="welcome-desc">
          Description
        </div>
        <div class="welcome-about">
          <!--делитесь информацией-->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="welcome-inputs">
        <br />
        <form action="" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
          <div class="facebook-button"><a href="/vkapp/index.php?vk=true&state=dbb8379b8bbb22b1c8d25ccd9ec42426" class="change_loading facebook-button">Войти в приложение</a></div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="welcome-full welcome-white">
  <div class="welcome-inner">
    <div class="welcome-row-title">Title</div>
    <div style="width:100%; padding-bottom:22px; font-size: 16px; color: #999;" class="welcome-user">Description</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="welcome-full">
</div>

</div>
<div class="footer">
  <div class="footer-container">
    
    
  </div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Т.к. это не сайт, а iframe приложение, то vk не разрешает запрашивать access_token, логин отдается напрямую через GET, вот так мы его получаем:

```html
//Polar: get VK iframe viewer_id
if(!isset($_SESSION['vk_auth_key']) || !isset($_SESSION['vk_viewer_id'])) {
  $_SESSION['vk_auth_key'] = $_GET['auth_key'];
  $_SESSION['vk_viewer_id'] = $_GET['viewer_id'];
  
  // Check auth_key & viewer_id
  $api_id = ********; // id приложения
  $secret_key = '*************'; // защищенный ключ
    $viewer_id = $_GET['viewer_id'];
    $auth_key = $_GET['auth_key'];
    
  if(md5($api_id."_".$viewer_id."_".$secret_key)!=$auth_key) exit('Key incorrect');
}
```

Comment: Права доступа в настройках приложения.

Comment: А где именно эти настройки искать? В настройках приложения нет никаких полей с правами доступа

Comment: Дайте ссылку на приложение, гляну. И $_POST['email']; откуда он приходит?

Answer (score 1):

Наверное, потому что у Вас есть кнопка "войти в приложение". Там, наверное, и есть запрос почты.

Но с другой стороны: зачем Вам та кнопка? Все функции и так доступны в iframe приложении вконтакте, если подключить библиотеку от вконтакте для вызова апи. И все данные для проверки пользователя есть.